# jQuery hide not working after AJAX call

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery `hide()` function to hide an element in two situations. One is the normal situation and it is working there. The other situation is that the part that contains the element is loaded through AJAX. I have written the script in the page to which the content is loaded to. But in this case, the function is not working. I have given the function in `onclick`. The click is triggered, but it is not hiding the element. As the click is triggered, I think there is no need to use `live()`

My element code is as follows :

```
<input type="button" onclick="addMoreElements(this.id);" value="Add" id="406" class="button">
```

and in the addMoreElements function I have

```
function addMoreElements(currentElement){
        $('#406').hide();
}
```

Comment: Any errors in console (or developer tool)?

Answer (score 1):

if you observe you are passing this.id to your javascript function and using explicitly $("#406") . Instead you can try this

```
function addMoreElements(currentelement){
    $("#"+currentelement).hide();
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Add" id="406" class="button" />​
```

jQuery

```
$('#406').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, please try defining your javascript before the html elements. That should do it.

Sample code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function addMoreElements(){
          $("#406").hide();     
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="addMoreElements();" value="Add" id="406" class="button" />
```

The reason behind this is,  when the browser sees an element with an event handler attribute is set, then the browser immediately checks for function pointers, if no function is defined yet, then even after function is defined, the event wont be handled correctly, so when you use attribute event handlers, make sure you include all your used functions are either defined at head tags or included in head tags.

Or just use jquery's event binders after a page load just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".element").click(function(){
      //do something with the element by using $(this)
    });
```

});